# bufferedReader.readline is returning null

Tags: java, android, file, io

just a really quick question i have a file in
AFC/save.txt
which has this in it

peter

now I use this code in Java and it returns null, any idea why?

```
//Android
try {
        InputStream fis = game.getFileIO().readFile("AFC/save.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        if(br.readLine() != null)
        {
                            Log.d("File", "Value : " + br.readLine() );
            player = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the value is null.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Which value is null?

At `if(br.readLine() != null)` you are reading in the first line of the file.

At `Log.d("File", "Value : " + br.readLine() );` you are at the second line of the file.

At  `player = br.readLine();` you are reading the third line of the file. If there is only one line in the file, this line will return null.

Try:

```
try {
    String temp;
    InputStream fis = game.getFileIO().readFile("AFC/save.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    if((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
          player = temp;
          Log.d("File", "Value : " + player );
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot each readline reads a new one :D, i have fixed it now cheers.

Comment: was waiting for it to allow me to :D